# Rename Cluster on Amazon ECS

Tags: amazon-ecs

I created an ECS cluster named "staging", and latter put it in production.
I would like to rename it to make it obvious this is the production one...
It seems that neither the website or aws-cli allows that.
Is there any way?
If no, how can I add some indication/attribute showing that this cluster is in production?
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not possible as of now with api, sdk or cli. You can terminate the cluster and create new cluster as per your environment.

Also, It is not a good idea to associate components of production to a cluster name staging.

As per your question, If you want to achieve blue-green deployment you can read below article to achieve that.

Ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/bluegreen-deployments-with-amazon-ecs/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm following the "blue-green" deployment technique, where the staging VM will become the production VM after being prepared and tested. Do you suggest another technique more adapted to ECS?

Comment: This is not how exactly you work on ECS. In ECS your blue-green deployment work with the containers not with the ECS Cluster instances. You may consider reading the link I have added up in my answer.